# How do i access a function i defined in my django view, inside the template (for UTF Encoding)

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have installed django-simple-gravatar and added that in my installed apps in the project.
Then i tried using it in my template as:

```
{% load gravatar %}

{% gravatar_url user.email 40 %}
```

But i got the following error:

> Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

So i made the "Profile" View Accordingly:

```
def Profile(request, pk):
    template = 'events/profile.html'
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(owner=user)
    liked_posts = Fav.objects.filter(user=user)

    def email_for_gravatar(self):
        return self.user.email.lower().encode("utf-8")

    ctx = {'user': user, 'posts': posts, 'liked_posts': liked_posts}
    return render(request, template, ctx)
```

And This is how i am trying to access the "email_for_gravtar" function inside my template, i may be wrong here:

```
{% gravatar_url user.profile.email_for_gravatar 40 %}
```

But the error message is still the same. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks like you use an older version of the package? Try upgrading the package: `pip install --upgrade django-simple-gravatar`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Nope, didn't work